# Search for a vector of values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to search several values in a column of a dataframe

The values in the column are unique.

Not all values are necessarily going to be there, and in that case it shoul return some `None` or `-1` or whatever.

An example:

```
ddff = pd.DataFrame({'A':['10A','20B','30A','40T','G50'],
                     'B':[15,25,3,6,10]},
                     index = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee'])
look_for = ['10A','20ZZZ','G50','30A']
```

I could always loop through `look_for` and search for each value.

How can I apply a search, such that the result would be the index for each value, if it exists, in an efficient way (since I know the column `'A'` has uniqu values) to get the following results:

```
['aa',None,'ee','cc']
```

Comment: So are you looking for whether any values in your `look_for` are missing?

Comment: Are you looking for `ddff[ddff['A'].isin(look_for)].index` but this only shows values that exist, you'd have to do some reverse lookup for missing values from the lookup list and add this as None or -1

Comment: I'm looking all the values in `look_for`, and want the index if they exist, and a `None` or similar value if they dont. I'm also interested that the results would be in the order in which they appear in `look_for`

Comment: Why not use a dict as a hash table?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be done using a list comprehension, thus conserving the order of the `look_for` variable :

```
[ddff.A.loc[ddff.A == i].index[0] if i in ddff['A'].values else None for i in look_for]
Out[7]: ['aa', None, 'ee', 'cc']
```